# ¿Como reproducir 2 audios a la vez con python (pygame)?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy tratando de reproducir un audio de fondo en un juego y otro de alerta cuando se seleccione una opción incorrecta. El detalle es que cuando uso mixer de pygame dos veces, el segundo audio anula al de fondo. He tratado de ponerlos en objetos diferentes y en clases distintas pero siguen anulandose.

```
class repoducirFondo ():
mixer.init()
def iniciar(self, ruta):
    mixer.music.load(ruta) 
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)  
    mixer.music.play() 

def detener(self):
    mixer.music.stop()





class reproAux1 ():
mixer.init() 
def detener(self):
    mixer.music.stop()  
def iniciar(self, ruta):
    mixer.music.load(ruta) 
    mixer.music.set_volume(2)  
    mixer.music.play()
```

Aqui llamo a los audios

```
    fondo = repoducirFondo()
    fondo.iniciar("../Datos/Multimedia/Menu.wav")
    
    alerta = reproAux1()
    alerta.iniciar("../Datos/Multimedia/Alerta1.wav")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tema ya lo respondí con un comentario, pero soy muy malo en el manejo del sitio, y no lo encontré, así que haré un ejemplo verificable:

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

ruta_fondo="Menu.wav"
ruta_sonido="Alerta1.wav"
```

Obvio que modificas las rutas como quieras.

```
mixer.music.load(ruta_fondo)
mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)  
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

No uso clases para los sonidos, así que te toca adaptarlo a lo que hagas
Lo importante es darle el valor -1  a la función play del sonido de fondo

```
running = True
while running:
    ventana.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                otro=mixer.Sound(ruta_sonido) 
                otro.play()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Acá es lo de siempre con pygame, lo único es que uso mixer.Sound en vez de music.load. lo reproduzco al presionar la tecla de espacio.

Espero que te oriente

Comment: Yo también recuerdo haber leído tu comentario y también estuve buscándolo para poner el URL en un comentario pero no lo encontré. Buen ejemplo, yo creo que algo que haría falta que aclararas es la razón por la que `play()` es `-1` para el sonido del fondo, lo demás lo veo claro y entendible. Te dejo mi voto, Saludos!

Comment: Me ha ayudado mucho a tomarme la idea de como hacerlo. Estaba trabajando el juego con terminal pura, es decir ingreso y salida de datos desde la consola, pero con tu ejemplo y un par de videos creo que sera mejor trabajar a lo grafico. Voy a mudar el código que ya tengo.  Por cierto, soy nuevo en python y no sabia el por que de tu ciclo infinito y del event, así que si alguien viene a esta pregunta le dejo este enlace donde explica a detalle cada parte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtk5lR150fg.  Gracias @tincopasan